# Could not load type 'ADODB.FieldsToInternalFieldsMarshaler' from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, adodb

I have the following code:

```
MAPITable mt = rStores.MAPITable;

        Recordset rs = new Recordset();
        rs = mt.ExecSQL(@"SELECT EntryID, ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF60102"" As PR_INSTANCE_KEY from Name");

        while (!rs.EOF)
        {
            var fields = ((dynamic)rs.Fields);
            for (int f = 0; f < fields.Count; f++)
            {
                var field = fields[f];
                var name = field.Name;
                var value = field.Value;
            }
            Debug.Print(rs.Fields["EntryID"].Value);
            Debug.Print(rs.Fields["PR_INSTANCE_KEY"].Value);
            rs.MoveNext();
```

When I try to access the recordset fields, I get the aforementioned error in the subject.  I saw the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666265/adodbcould-not-load-type-adodb-fieldstointernalfieldsmarshaler-from-assembly), but that did not help me.

**UPDATE**:  Nevermind - workaround listed [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/476238/error-while-using-adodb-recordset)

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark it, so the question is cleared from the "unanswered questions" queue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately your link to the workaround is broken. Page Not found. I found the following workaround.

ADODB Properties from References:
Embed Interop Types: false
Copy local: true
specific version (in English maybe isolated?): false

Comment: This was absolutely my problem - it was using a local version from the GAC instead of copying a stable version we had in a reference folder.  Thanks.